# How to delete more than one element from an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, element

I have a question..How can I delete more than one elements from an one dimensional array in C++? Suppose I have an array A={1,3,5,8,9,7} and I want to delete suppose 3,5,7 from array A. Please kindly let me know if anyone knows any efficient algorithm.

Comment: There's always `std::remove_if`.

Comment: You cannot "delete eleemnts from an array". Arrays have fixed size. You should use a standard library container instead.

Answer (score 7):

Arrays are not resizable in C++.  The best option for a resizable container is [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which you would use as:

```
    std::vector<int> v = {1,3,5,8,9,7};
```

and then to remove elements by some predicate:

```
   auto new_end = std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                                 std::bind(std::less<int>(), _1, 6));
```

But this only shuffles the elements around your `vector` so that they are all at the end.  To the actually erase them, you need to call:

```
   v.erase(new_end, v.end());
```